# Купаться в/на озере

Tags: грамматика

Из интернет-СМИ:

> Названы семь озер Нижегородской области, на которых можно купаться
> Региональное управление Роспотребнадзора не рекомендует купаться на
> четырех прилегающих к ним пляжах.
>
> https://www.nn.ru/text/gorod/2021/06/10/69963161/

На мой слух, словосочетание "купаться на озере" звучит несколько странно (примерно как "купаться на реке/море/водоёме"). Сомнение также вызывает "купаться на пляже".

Насколько нормативно такое употребление?

Comment: нинасколько - просто ошибка

Comment: ну, "на пляже" - точно не ошибка

Comment: «На озере» отвечает на вопрос «где?», а «в озере» — на вопрос «в чём?»

Comment: Предлог «на» указывает на местность , где можно купаться, т.е. в случае с «озером» , «пляжем» это как бы другое значение, поэтому всё вполне употребимо.

Comment: Нет, это не ошибка - просто "озеро" тут фигурирует как "место в общем"... В русском полно таких образований. "На озере, на Украине, на Псковщине, на полях..." и т.д.

Comment: Если вы говорите - "на озере", вы описываете место и пейзаж в общем.. как место действия и событий - вообще...  например - купались вы там много раз, загорали, ели, пили, по усам текло, что это за озеро и конкретный момент времени и процесс - все равно.... сюда входит и пляж, и девки и небо голубое и т.д... в общем - пейзаж в общем, и общее место :> 
Если вы говорите - "купаться в озере", вы описываете конкретный процесс и акцентируесь на нем и на озере как на скоплении воды, где и происходит этот процесс...  акт купания ... в этой фразе, более конкретизированно...

Comment: совершенно правильно сказано "«На озере» отвечает на вопрос «где?», а «в озере» — на вопрос «в чём?» – Yellow Sky"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое употребление не часто, но [встречается в литературе](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20&gramm1=V%2C%28indic%7Cimper%7Cimper2%7Cpartcp%7Cger%29&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%BD%D0%B0&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2):

> *― Я, баринъ, до двадцати пяти лѣтъ не зналъ какія такія женщины, а бывало съ дѣвушками же вмѣстѣ купаюсь на рѣчкѣ...*
> [А. А. Черкасов. Из записок сибирского охотника (1888)]
>
> *Вчера и сегодня купался на море ― на пляже в курорте.*
> [К. И. Чуковский. Дневник  (1925)]
>
> *Вчера в три часа поехал в Cannes, ...  купался на пляже Grand Нotеl'я;*
> [И. А. Бунин. Дневники (1940-1953))]
>
> *... Гуляли. Купались на озере.*
> [Д. Каралис. Автопортрет (1999)]
>
> *... по дороге купались на безлюдных и живописных пляжах.* [А. Берсенева. Возраст третьей любви (2005)]

Ну а "*(не) рекомендуется купаться на (список пляжей, местностей, водоемов)*" ― это теперь [стандартный канцелярский оборот](http://,https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5), нравится нам это или нет.

Answer (score -2):

Вы *правильно* обратили внимание на *речевые ошибки*, допущенные либо сотрудниками пресс-службы ведомства "Роспотребнадзор", либо толкователями его рекомендаций. Это в лучшем случае *канцеляризмы* внутреннего пользования. Следовало написать "**в** которых можно купаться" и "**отдыхать** на прилегающих пляжах". Вот полная статья из Словаря сочетаемости слов русского языка (изд. Русский язык, 1983, с. 256):

> КУПАТЬСЯ, купаюсь, купаешься, купаются, несов. Погружаясь в воду,
> освежаться, плавать, плескаться и т. п. Купаться г д е :(предлог«в» с
> предл.) ~в море, в океане, в реке, в  озере,  в  пруду,  в  бассейне
> ..., (предлог«на» с предл.)—на середине чего л. (реки ...), на
> каком-л. (глубоком, мелком ...) месте •••; (предлоги
> «около»/*возле»/«;у» с род.)~ около/возле/у [самого] берега,
> около/возле/у  камней,  около/возле/у  скалы  ...; (предлог«недалеко
> от» с род.)~ недалеко от берега, недалеко от какого-л. места ...;
> (предлог«рядом с» с твор.)~ рядом с берегом, рядом с молом ...
> Купаться как ч а с т о :~ часто, редко, ежедневно, каж-дый день ...
> Купаться к а к :~ охотно, с удовольствием ...Любить,  ходить,  пойти,
> побежать,  начать,  кончить,  позвать кого-л., разрешить кому-л.,
> запретить кому-л., пустить кого-л. ... купаться.О Летом  мы  ежедневно
> купались  в  море.  В  этом  году  мы начали купаться в мае.—Ты
> сегодня пойдёшь купаться?—Нет, мне не хочется, сегодня очень холодно

http://vassilenkoanatole.narod.ru/slovar-sochet_slov.pdf

Comment: и "пляж" и "озеро" тут фигурируют как "место вообще" :) 
как тут было сказано - "«На озере» отвечает на вопрос «где?», а «в озере» — на вопрос «в чём?» "

Comment: @Пилум Если вы опираетесь на приведенную словарную статью, то обратите внимание: не "**место _вообще**_", а _место реки (озера, пруда, бассейна)_ (глубокое, мелкое, середина и т. п.). Пляж к таким "местам" не относится.

Comment: – Alex_ander, я опираюсь на русский язык.